# Retrieving an image using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

**My Express Code::**

```
ar express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'test123'
});

connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7005);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM test456', function(err, rows, fields)

    {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

} );



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

---

**I have used following SQL queries to create a corrosponding database**

```
CREATE TABLE test456 ( _id INT(10), name VARCHAR(30), image VARCHAR(50));
```

.

```
INSERT INTO test456 ( _id,name,image ) VALUES ( 1,"nature","http://54.218.73.244:7005/image.jpg" );
```

then

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test456;
+------+--------+-------------------------------------+
| _id  | name   | image                               |
+------+--------+-------------------------------------+
|    1 | nature | http://54.218.73.244:7005/image.jpg |
+------+--------+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**but when i try the url in by browser i am not able to fetch the image**

```
http://54.218.73.244:7005/image.jpg
```

i get output as::

```
Cannot GET /image.jpg
```

Note:: I have checked that there is a image in the specified location,

where am i going wrong in coding

Comment: Do you want your node instance to act as a proxy and fetch the image at the location stored in MySQL ?

Comment: I dont know how node acts as a proxy but, i want the image to be displayed on accessing by browser

Comment: Ok, but where is the data of your image ? You only have a URL in MySQL, so I'm assuming it's not there.

Comment: data is there in the root .... like it is in /image.jpg ..... but i am not able to access it

Comment: can you join the node.js chat ? It'll be easier to help you there.

Comment: Yes ... i am in node js chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37519/discussion-between-sky-and-laurent-perrin)

Answer (score 0):

Following our discussion in chat, try this:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'test123'
});

connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7005);

// this will catch
app.get('/countries/:country_id',function(req, res) {
  // you don't know what was passed, so escape it.
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM test456 where country_id = ?', [mysql.escape(req.params.country_id)], function(err, rows, fields) {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });
} );



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```